# Django - how to handle lookup that return Zero rows

Tags: django, lookup, rows, zero

What is the best way to deal with 0 records return
from a database lookup?

I have UserDetails object (table) that has a foreign
key to the default django User object (table)

How to deal with Users who don't yet have any
row/records in the UserDetails object (table)?

If I do this lookup on a User that has zero
rows in the UserDetails table I get this error:

IndexError at /my-page/

list index out of range

```
@login_required
def my_page(request):
    """ A function to render My Page
    """

    user_details = UserDetails.objects.filter(id=2)[0]

    # Return rendered HTML
    return render_to_response('my_page.html', RequestContext(request,
                                                             {
                                                              'city_town': user_details.city_town,
                                                              'state_province': user_details.state_province,
                                                              }))
# end def
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is get the user details, or return None, so your template can render the appropriate thing. You do so, by catching the error trying to retrieve a single object, and setting the variable to None if it fails.

```
try:
    user_details = UserDetails.objects.get(id=2)
except UserDetails.DoesNotExist:
    user_details = None

# the rest of your code
```

Then handle a None value in your template:

```
# template
{% if user_details %}
    # render details
{% else %}
    # render form inputs
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi, Well I like the template to either output a value or not. Ex: City Town: {{ city_town }} <br /> State / Province: {{ state_province }}. If the values are empty the user can enter new values. If they are not empty they can update them.

Comment: I think it's this part that is currently throwing the error: 'city_town': user_details.city_town,